# How to ignore prefix on certain models? CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, mode

I have to read data from a table called `sys_sbu` which is in the same database as my app. However, I have set `tr_` to be the prefix of all my tables. When I tried to use `$useTable = 'sys_sbu'` on my model, it determined it to be `tr_sys_sbu`. How do I force it to ignore the prefix?

Comment: `public $tablePrefix = ''`

Comment: @WesleySchleumer post it as an answer so that this question can be marked 'answered' and gain some reputation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, try this:

```
class ExampleModel{
    var $useTable = "example";
    var $tablePrefix = "";
}
```

It's alright now :D